# Do centrifugal forces occur when the world around me is spinning but I am at rest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

So I understand that when you take, let's just say a plate, and you spin it, any objects on it would be "pulled" outwards (Because they want to follow a straight line rather than a circular one). But if I stood on this plate it would look like the world is spinning, but this spinning world causes me to fly off the platform (plate). So it got me wondering, what if I took a really massive object (like a planet or star), had it spin really fast, and stood on top of a still plate above it. It would look no different than when I stood on the spinning plate (from my perspective), but would I still feel myself being pulled outwards?

Comment: Are you standing on the spinning massive thing?

Comment: No, just set up where it looks like the world around me is spinning but I am not making contact with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between forces like gravity and "pseudo-forces" like centripetal forces is that the pseudo forces are caused by your frame of reference, while real forces are caused by objects themselves (or fields, or whatnot).  It's going to take some math to get there, but we can answer your question based on this.

When we are predicting what we expect to feel in any situation, we are using "equations of motion," whether at a conscious academic level or at a more intuitive level.  We use these equations of motion to predict where something will be, or what forces we will feel.

In an *inertial* frame of reference, these equations are very simple.  Generally speaking, they all look like $F=ma$.  These inertial reference frames "make sense," because, in practical day-to-day situations, the rotation of the earth is slow enough that we're *almost* in an inertial frame.  Throw a ball, and it will follow a "parabolic" arc to its destination, in exactly the way you intuit.

Now consider other reference frames besides inertial ones, such as rotating frames.  What you find is that if you try to simply apply $F=ma$ in a rotating frame, it yields results that are incompatible with what an observer in the inertial frame would see.  But clearly you are both looking at the same situation (such as the same ball toss), so one has to be right.  The answer is that $F=ma$ is not the equations of motion for a rotating frame.  You can actually work out the math to find the equations of motion in the rotating frame, starting from the equations of motion in an inertial frame and simply doing some math to calculate what would occur in rotating frames.  The answer is that, in a rotating frame, the equations of motion take the form $F=m(a + \omega^2r - 2\Omega \times v)$, where $\omega$ is the angular rotation rate, $\Omega$ is a vector along the axis of rotation whose magnitude is $\omega$, $r$ is the distance from the center of rotation, and $v$ is the velocity of the object.  If one observer, using an inertial frame, uses their equations of motion to predict the path of an object, and a second observer using a rotating frame uses this more complicated equation of motion to do their predictions, then their predictions will line up exactly.  More importantly, we have found experimentally that both will yield correct predictions.

In the above equation, the $\omega^2r$ term is the centripetal acceleration term, and the $2\Omega\times v$ term is known as the Coriolis term.  These are terms which appear in the equations of motion in a rotating frame which do not appear in the equations of motion in a non-rotating frame.

So, to answer your question, the difference between you standing on a still plate over a spinning planet and you standing on a spinning plate without the planet is which set of equations of motion you are using.  If you are on a still plate, you are using an inertial frame of reference, thus you would use $F=ma$ to predict how objects move in your world.  If you are on a spinning plate, and using your own frame of reference, that frame of reference is rotating, so you use $F=m(a + \omega^2r - 2\Omega \times v)$, where $\omega$, and you will find that all objects appear to be affected by a centrifugal (and Coriolis) effect.

What might be more interesting is to consider the case where you are on a spinning plate, and predict the effects as viewed by both you and an observer on the still planet beneath you.  When you do your predictions using $F=m(a + \omega^2r - 2\Omega \times v)$, where $\omega$, you will find that all parts of your body are "pulled outwards" by a centrifugal acceleration.  Meanwhile, a ground observer would use $F=ma$ and see no centrifugal acceleration.  So what gives?

The ground observer, being inertial, is the easiest to work through intuitively.  All objects travel in a straight line unless acted upon by a force.  What the ground observer sees is you, on the plate, traveling on a straight line, which will lead you to eventually leave the plate altogether, like a yo-yo which is swung around and then the string is suddenly cut.  However, they will see you interacting with the plate via friction.  You will push on the plate with a force, and the plate will push back on you.  This means there is a *real* force pushing you towards the center of the plate.

In the rotating frame, we see things differently.  What was a natural inclination to "go in a straight line" in an inertial frame looks like its moving away from the center.  Something has to "keep the object where it is," to oppose this center-fleeing effect.  That something is a force applied to the plate, which then causes a normal force applied by the plate onto you, which counteracts the centripetal effects, keeping you in your spot on the plate.

Comment: Centripetal force is not a pseudo force. Don't you mean *centrifugal* force?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are spinning in space (in relation to the stars). Your arms will be pulled outside, and the faster you rotate, the higher the pull. This is the way you can decide you are turning and not the universe. In a Newtonian universe, you will always have to say that it's **you** who is rotating.

In general relativity though (in the Einsteinian universe), the situation becomes different. In the present distribution of mass throughout the universe, you can still decide that it's **you** who is rotating [though you can't rotate, on the outermost parts of your body (your hands), contrary to the Newtonian universe, faster than the speed of light].

Now suppose the mass of the universe is concentrated in a big shell around you. In this case, you can say that it's you who is rotating, but it's equally valid to say that it's the shell of mass that is rotating, which causes the pull on your arms. You can compare this effect with [gravitomagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism).

So, concerning your example of you standing on a rotating disc, it's **not** the universe, which for you seems to be rotating, that creates the pull on you from your perspective. If you're standing on a non-rotating plate above a heavy star, the situation is not the same as the one in which you're standing on a rotating plate (all other objects in the Universe won't rotate around you). You will feel no centrifugal force pulling you outwards. You **do** feel the gravitomagnetic pull caused by the rotation of the heavy star.

Comment: But what if the point in which the shell is rotating around, isn't directly at your position, so it would seem that you are a certain distance away from the center which the axis of rotation goes through? Would the equivalence still apply?

Comment: What do you mean by: But what if the point in which the shell is rotating around, isn't directly at your position?  **You** (that is your CM) are in the center of that shell, in line with the axis of rotation (if not, other parts than your arms would be forced away from your center of mass). I can't see the connection with the equivalence principle, which always applies but maybe I don't understand correctly what you mean...

Comment: I think what you mean now. If you're not at the center of the sphere, you can still say that is you who is rotating or that it's the massive shell. Both perspectives are equivalent. The difference between standing at the center and off-center, is simply that you experience different pulls on your body: when you're standing at the center the pull you feel is symmetrical around the axis of rotation and thus around you (and, as said, you can't tell if you or the shell is rotating), while when you're standing off-center, the pull ain't symmetrical around you.

Comment: The equivalence principle still applies (which is the reason both perspectives are equivalent). It (obviously) also applies also in our Universe but here is the distribution of mass such, that you actually **can** tell if it's you who is rotating, or if it's the Universe that's rotating. The Universe around you has an enormous mass, so it costs an almost infinite amount of kinetic energy (by **almost infinite**, which is of course nonsense, I mean a huge amount of kinetic energy), and you can be certain that it's you who's rotating. **But doesn't the same holds for the massive shell**. Guess!